# Lightbox problems - Not centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've created a lightbox for an image gallery and whenever I open up an image, it won't open up correctly. It always shows up at the very bottom of the page.

I don't know what to do as nothing I've tried has worked. I've provided the code I have used, both HTML and CSS. I'm open to using JS if needed but would prefer to stick to HTML and CSS. [I have provided a link to my HTML code on pastebin as it won't cooperate when pasting](https://pastebin.com/fZ6WCEvj) but my CSS code is here.

CSS

```
.gallery {
  margin: 10px 75px;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 230px;
  height: 170px;
  padding: 3px;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: 1s;
}

.gallery img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

I just want to be able to click an image and it shows up as an image gallery where I can slide across to different images.

Comment: You have no positioning on your gallery element so it's always going to display relative to where the element exists in the document, below your header and container. Are you looking to center your gallery within the viewport?

Comment: I am yes. Sorry, I'm still learning and this project is for a course so I'm bound to forget some stuff. Could you possibly give me some advice as to where the positioning needs to go?

Comment: I see you're using a lightbox library. Why not just utilise that? Seems to do what you're asking in this post.

Comment: The code you are providing, has a relative assets that are not in place.